# Error (String index out of range: 4) java

Tags: java, string, netbeans, condiciones

Alguien me puede ayudar? El problema que me plantearon es: Desarrollar un programa que acepte mediante el teclado una cadena de caracteres, encontrar cuántos caracteres son a, cuántos e, cuántos  i, cuántos  o, y cuántos  son u, desplegar el resultado en pantalla.

y al ejecutar el código me aparece un error en la ejecución del comando, alguien sabe donde se encuentra el error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
                                           
public class Problema1 
{  
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
                       
        String Frase;
                          
        int conta=0;
                      
        int conte=0;
                    
        int conti=0;
           
        int conto=0;
                           
        int contu=0;
                                    
        Scanner L=new Scanner(System.in);
                                            
        System.out.println("Ingresa una cadena de caracteres");
                                                            
        Frase=L.next();
                                           
        for (int i= 0 ; i<= Frase.length(); i++){
                                   
            if(Frase.charAt(i)==('a'))
                                              
                conta=conta+1;
                                    
            else if (Frase.charAt(i)=='e')
                                               
                conte=conte+1;
                                             
            else if (Frase.charAt(i)=='i')
                                                 
                conti=conti+1;
                                              
            else if(Frase.charAt(i)=='o')
                                                           
                conto=conto+1;
                                                               
            else 
                                                  
                contu=contu+1;
                                                                         
        }
        System.out.println("La cantidad de a es: "+conta+"\n La cantidad de e es"+conte+"\n La cantidad de i es"+conti+"\n La cantidad de o es"+conto+"\n La cantidad de u es"+contu);
                                                                                    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: probaste Frase.length() -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el bucle `for`, donde has indicado `i<= Frase.length()`, por lo que la última iteración se sale de los límites del string ya que al usar `<=` estás sobrepasando la última posición..

Para ello debes indicar:

```
for (int i= 0 ; i< Frase.length(); i++){ }
```

O bien

```
for (int i= 0 ; i <= Frase.length()-1; i++){ }
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo cambiar la estrucutra `if/else` ya que el `else` aceptará como caracter "u" cualquier letra que no sea "a", "e", "i", o "o".

Comment: En serio muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto después de ese cambio